# integrating azure key vault to red hat Linux servers

Tags: azure-keyvault

we have 120 redhat linux servers. we apply security patches to all of them every month.
we are passing username and password through hosts file in plain text format.
can some help me how to integrate azure key vault and how to pass that password during security patching time

Comment: For remote access, wouldn't SSH (public key authentication) be simpler? It certainly has built-in tooling, or popular external tooling. Getting username/password from Key Vault and storing that in a plain-text file is pretty straight forward, but not secure.

Comment: We concerned about security, that’s why we choose azure key vault for security .

Comment: Key Vault securely stores secrets, keys, and certificates. If you download that content and share it across the wire, it's no longer securely stored. This question isn't really about how to use Key Vault, but just how to get data from it - using it merely as a storage mechanism. The only thing that comes close to what you want is if your linux VMs are in Azure. You can use Managed Identity to allow those VMs to securely use secrets in Key Vault: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-linux-vm-access-arm

Comment: If all you want to do is get a username and password from Key Vault, see our samples at https://learn.microsoft.com/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-net/azuresecuritykeyvaultsecrets-samples/. Once you get any username and password stored in Key Vault, using those to authenticate to your servers is a separate matter that greatly depends on what remote management tool you're using. SSH is a common tool in this case.